# Interfering higher frequency waves to create a lower frequency one

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics

Once I saw a demo where multiple speakers were outputting inaudible sounds (I assume very high frequency) that would interfere at certain locations to be audible.  It has fascinated me for some time but I can't figure out how it works.  Right now I have some use for something similar, so I guess it's time to understand.

Can I output two audio signals (either inaudible or appearing to be something else) that, when superposed, will interfere to create a third?  Imagine, say, some music, where each channel on its own seems normal but when both channels are played together you hear a secret message (ooooh spooooky).

I know some basics of Fourier analysis and DSP, enough to find my way through with a few pointers on how this technique works, if it exists.

Comment: No time (or space) to speculate in more detail, but (i) Beats (e.g. $\cos x + \cos y = 2\cos(\frac{1}{2}(x + y))\cos(\frac{1}{2}(x - y))$) could yield an audible difference even if the summands are out-of-range for the ear; (ii) The steganography technique of hiding an independent signal in low-order bits of an image could presumably be used with audio signals. That is, one channel would contain a loud signal and low-volume "hidden" signal, the other would contain the loud signal out of phase, so hearing both would (largely) cancel the loud parts, leaving the hidden part.